# Advanced module unit test setup in Julia

Tags: unit-testing, julia

I have custom Julia package, which has hopefully quite standard structure. I have single package, `src` directory with sources and then `test` directory with all the tests.
In my package I have 4 modules (1 "main" and entrypoint module) and then 3 submodules.

I am slowly adding tests to `tests` directory. Tests are importing modules with `using` keyword.
Now problem is, very often I am testing some "private" or unnecessary method to be visible to outside and I have to export those functions even though I would not export them otherwise.

How to solve this? I was thinking that each module could have "Private" submodule containing all these "private" functions and constants used for unit testing so that I don't bloat exports of my clean module API.

Comment: you can always test functions that are not exported by calling them with `MyModule.MySubModule.func()`

Comment: That's pretty much perfect solution to my problem!

Comment: Or you can `import` the specif private function(s).. this has the advantage that your test code can resemble your actual module code, no need then to add prefixes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copied from comments as that seems to be the solution OP is looking for

---

you can always test functions that are not exported by calling them with `MyModule.MySubModule.func()`